# Confused about templates

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have to deal with a code, which I am totally confused about.

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T, T t = T()>
class A
{
private:
    template<bool b>
    class B
    {
    public:
        static const int m_n = b ? 1 : 0;
    };

public:
    static const int m_value = B<(t > T())>::m_n - B<(t < T())>::m_n;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << A<int, -9>::m_value
              << A<bool, true>::m_value
              << A<char>::m_value << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Could you comment about following line?

```
static const int m_value = B<(t > T())>::m_n - B<(t < T())>::m_n;
```

How *greater* and *less* operator is used here?

I cannot figure out how second template is used:

```
template<bool b>
```

Comment: What exactly don't you understand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`B` is a (nested) class template with a `bool` template parameter (`b`); its static member `m_n` is `1` when `b` is `true`, and `0` when `b` is `false`.

`t > T()` tests whether the value `t` (which is a template parameter of `A`) is greater than a value-initialised `T`. Since `T` must be a valid type for non-type template parameters, `T()` is equivalent to `T(0)`, i.e. a zero expressed in the correct type.

The result of that test is then used as a template argument for `B`. Equivalent code would look like this:

```
public:
    static const T t0 = T();
    static const bool b1 = t > t0;
    static const bool b2 = t < t0;
    static const int m_value = B<b1>::m_n - B<b2>::m_n;
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that the default constructor `T()` zero initialises built in types. So

```
B<(t > T())>::m_n
```

is 1 if `t` is positive and 0 otherwise, and

```
B<(t < T())>::m_n
```

is 1 if `t` is negative and 0 otherwise. Hence

```
B<(t > T())>::m_n - B<(t < T())>::m_n
```

is 1 if `t` is positive, 0 if it is zero and -1 if it is negative.